# VersionOne Rest Query Deleted Items

Tags: rest, versionone

I am using the VersionOne Rest interface but not the provided VersionOne SDK for Java or C#. A stakeholder has requested I modify a tool that queries all VersionOne issues to also query all deleted issues. I can see how to do this with `showOptions=Deleted` in the webUI, however, when I try to add it to the rest URI it seems to be ignored. My rest call still will output all the open and closed issues, but no deleted issues are included. Any thoughts? Is this possible?

VersionOne Version: 17.1.2.103

Example URI: `hostName/VersionOne/rest-1.Oauth.v1/Data/Issue?sel=field1,field2.name&showOptions=Deleted`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this in what I think is an unintuitive way, by checking where IsDeleted=true. What worked for me: `hostName/VersionOne/rest-1.Oauth.v1/Data/Issue?sel=field1,field2.name&where=IsDeleted=%27true%27`

I tried checking where the AssetState was set to Deleted, Deleted (Dead), and ID 255 however all got no responses. I was able to set AssetState to Active or ID 64 and both got the expected results so it seems weird that Deleted/ID 255 did not work.

Reference for AssetState details: https://community.versionone.com/Digital.ai_Agility_Integrations/Developer_Library/Getting_Started/Platform_Concepts/Asset_State